# VSTOInstaller.exe error 0x8007007F The procedure entry point GetFileVersionInfoExW could not be located in the dynamic link library VERSION.dll

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I've got VSTO project for Outlook, developed in VS 2012.

When I install it under Windows XP, where Visual Studio 2010 or later version is installed, I've got no problems.

When I install it by clicking .vsto file under Windows XP where no Visual Studio is installed, **VSTOInstaller.exe** fails with **0x8007007F** error.

When I install it from command line (in fact it's the same)

```
"c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe" /install file://.../OutlookAddIn.vsto
```

I get

**The procedure entry point GetFileVersionInfoExW could not be located in the dynamic link library VERSION.dll**

Windows installer 4.5, VSTO 2010 runtime are installed on the problem machine.

How to fix it? 
Thanks.

Comment: When the machine is *this* borken then you would never want to install your software on it.  Shove it out of a 4th story window or ask somebody to re-image it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I suppose VSTO 2010 runtime downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48217 has a bug in VSTOInstaller.exe (version 10.0.60724.0).

Uninstalling it and reinsalling older version from distributive of VS 2015/2012/2010 (find file vstor40_x86.exe or vstor40_x64.exe) fixes the problem.

VSTOInstaller.exe from VS 2015 has version 10.0.50903.0 - it is OK.

Comment: Can you help me to download the 10.0.50903.0 version? I can't find it.

Thanks!